# How to cut a segment or several segment from one line?

Tags: text-processing, cut

Here is one line sample logs

```
03 Jun 2017/13:51:32:553 DEBUG connectors.BaseConnector [] [] [] - Request Message is <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:_0="abc" xmlns:_1="abcd" xmlns:soapenv="abcde" xmlns:v1="abcdef"><soapenv:Header><_0:Trace mustUnderstand="false"></_0:Trace><_0:MsgDetl mustUnderstand="false"><_0:MsgUID>20150103135132968917</_0:MsgUID></_0:MsgDetl><_0:ExtendedHeader><CredentialsRqHdr><PartyId>123456789</PartyId><LoginName>Userid</LoginName><PartyAuth><SecTokenKey><SessKey>SessionID</SessKey></SecTokenKey></PartyAuth></CredentialsRqHdr></_0:ExtendedHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><v1:actionList><_1:CommonRq><_1:OrgCode>2009</_1:OrgCode></_1:CommonRq><_1:CustId>12345678</_1:CustId><v1:e123><v1:SortOrder>L</v1:SortOrder><v1:SortSeq>D</v1:SortSeq></v1:e123></v1:actionList></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

The keywords are `MsgUID`, `LoginName`, `CustId`, and the position is not fixed.
I want output is like below:

```
03 Jun 2017/13:51:32:553 MsgUID, LoginName, CustId
```

Comment: FYI that is a terrible date format, guaranteed to mess up the sort order at the start of each month or year.  there's a reason why the [ISO 8601 Date Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is so widely used - it always sorts correctly.  It's also standard and unambiguous, you never have to guess which digits are month and which are day (i.e. MMDD as used in most of the world vs DDMM as used in the US)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `sed` for that:

```
sed 's/\(.*:[0-9]* \).*<_0:MsgUID>\([^<]*\).*/\1, \2/'
```

for the timestamp and MsgUID. You can easily expand it to include LoginName and CustId as well: Form regular expressions to match those parts and enclose the parts you want to keep in `\(\)`. In the replacement string you can reuse those parts as `\1'  for the first,`\2`for the second and so on. Try to solve it by understanding the expession for`MsgUID`. If you don't succeed, post your code in the question.

Comment: working perfectly...thanks a lot. I will try to figure out the rest...

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed` you could do it as:

```
sed -Ee '
   s/^/\n\n/
   s/\n\n/&\n/;s/[[:blank:]]+/\n/3;s/(.*)\n\n(.*)\n(.*)\n/\1\3\n\n\2/
   s|<_0:MsgUID>|\n|;s|</_0:MsgUID>|\n|;s/(.*)\n\n(.*)\n(.*)\n/\1 \3\n\n\2/
   s|<LoginName>|\n|;s|</LoginName>|\n|;s/(.*)\n\n(.*)\n(.*)\n/\1 \3\n\n\2/
   s|<_1:CustId>|\n|;s|</_1:CustId>|\n|;s/(.*)\n\n(.*)\n(.*)\n/\1 \3\n\n\2/
   s/\n\n.*//
' log.file
```

---

## Explanation

- We place a marker, `\n\n`, at the beginning of line. All the matches found in the line are thrown to this marker's left.
- First we isolate the  date time portion and then move it to the left of marker.
- In all the subsequent steps, we similarly isolate the tags of interest, and throw the tag values to the marker's left.
- When we are done, we simply delete everything to the right of the marker in cluding the marker and what remains in the pattern space is what we want.
- Note: this method is extensible to include as many tags that you need.

---

## Results

```
03 Jun 2017/13:51:32:553 20150103135132968917 Userid 12345678
```

---

Another way is using the Perl regexes:

```
perl -lne '$,=$";
print /^(?:\S+\s+){2}\S+|<(?:_0:MsgUID|LoginName|_1:CustId)>\K(?:.*?)(?=<)/g' log.file
```

Here we set the `OFS` `$,` to `$"` which is `space`. The perl regex `/..../g` will output all the non-lookaround matches in a list, which then shall the printed space separated due to the OFS value already put in place.